# Given two connected Sortable JQuery lists, how can I know which container an element was dropped on?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two sortable containers on a form.  These containers are used for moving columns back and forth for a dynamic report. Since both containers are connected with one another, users can drag and drop items left-to-right, vice-versa, or a user can click-and-drag an item and drop it back on it's original container.

In my `stop()` method, I need to determine which container the item was dropped on.

You can always know the original container by looking at the `sender` value in the `ui` parameter that is passed to your stop event.  However, I can't seem to find any documentation or any examples explaining how to know the final container that your element was dropped on.

Does anyone know how to discern this within a the stop method?

Regarding the example below, you can drag and drop, back and forth from the left to the right.  You can also pick up an item and move it around on the right-hand side, up and down the list.

However, I have no way of knowing in the `stop:...` event method *which* container received the element.

### CODE

```js
$("#left-side").sortable({
  connectWith: "#right-side",
  update: function(e, info) {
    $(this).find('li').sort(function(a, b) {
        return +a.dataset.sort - +b.dataset.sort;
      })
      .appendTo(this);
  }
});
$("#right-side").sortable({
  connectWith: "#left-side",
  stop: function(e, ui) {
    ui.item.after(ui.item.find("li"))
    //
    // How can I determine which side the element was dropped on?
    //
  }
});
$("#left-side, #right-side").find('li').attr('data-sort', function() {
  return $(this).index('body ul.ui-sortable li');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<style>
  ul {
    border: 1px solid Black;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top
  }
  
  li {
    background-color: Azure;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted Gray
  }

</style>
<h1>Click items to select them</h1>
<ul id="left-side">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
<ul id="right-side">
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li>Six</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both sides you need to implement de function **stop**.
In this function you can use:

```
var parent = ui.item.parent();
```

To get the ul container.